# The difference between the different types of rhodamine

Tags: homework, synthesis

What is the difference between different type of rhodamine, for example rhodamine red and rhodamine green?
are these two type of rhodamine (red & green) have a good Raman signal?
We would like examples of Raman signals of these two types of rhodamine.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! I think your first question can be answered by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodamine). It would be helpful if you could provide the structures of the compounds in your post. Please also have a look at the [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/4945) which applies to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Rhodamine green
CAS: 189200-71-3
[image]

Rhodamine Red
CAS: --
[image]